# Get list of Keras variables

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'd like to compare variables in a Keras model with those from a TensorFlow checkpoint. I can get the TF variables like this:

`vars_in_checkpoint = tf.train.list_variables(os.path.join("./model.ckpt"))`

How can I get the Keras variables to compare from my `model`?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the variables of a Keras model via `model.weights` (list of `tf.Variable` instances).

Answer (score 0):

To get the variable's name you need to access it from the weight attribute of the model's layer. Something like this:

`names = [weight.name for layer in model.layers for weight in layer.weights]`

And to get the shape of the weight:

`weights = [weight.shape for weight in model.get_weights()]`